# Query parent table on multiple child conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables (Mail and MailTag), each containing over 500,000 records so query efficiency is very important.

For each email record (Mail) there is a minimum of one tag recorded in the MailTag child table. Every email can have multiple tag (so 1 or many).

Parent table is:

Mail:

| IdEmail | Subject | Other... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... |
| 2 | ... | ... |
| 3 | ... | ... |
| 4 | ... | ... |
| 5 | ... | ... |
| etc. | ... | ... |

and child table

MailTag:

| Id | IdTag | IdMail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 | 2 |
| 3 | 9 | 3 |
| 4 | 10 | 2 |
| 5 | 10 | 3 |
| 6 | 11 | 3 |
| 7 | 12 | 3 |
| 8 | 9 | 5 |
| 9 | 10 | 5 |
| 10 | 11 | 5 |
| 11 | 12 | 5 |
| 12 | 9 | 6 |
| 13 | 11 | 6 |
| 14 | 13 | 6 |
| etc. |  |  |

I would like to query emails by tags in two general scenarios:

**Scenario 1:** (Tags whitelist 9, 11)
Select all emails that have **both** IdTag=9 and IdTag=11. Returns emails 3, 5 and 6.

**Scenario 2:** (Tags whitelist 9, 11 and blacklist 10, 12)
Select all emails that have **both** IdTag=9 and IdTag=11 **but not any** of the IdTag=10 or IdTag=12. Returns only email 6.

White/blacklist can contain 0 or more IdTags. **EDIT**: this part has to be parameterized.

How can I write queries for both scenarios? Preferably avoiding any kind of loops ("while loop"), if possible.

Comment: Seems like a `JOIN` and a conditional `COUNT` in the `HAVING` is what you are after.

Comment: @Larnu I was thinking about COUNT in HAVING, but I cannot figure out how to account for the 'blacklisted' tags...

Comment: How is this parametrised? A table type parameter? Are they 2 separate ones for the white and black lists?

Comment: Yes. A table type parameter (just a list of INTEGERS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, use a conditional aggregate in the `HAVING`. For just needing those tags, then use the following:

```sql
SELECT M.IdEmail,
       M.Subject,
       M.[Other...]
FROM dbo.Mail
     JOIN dbo.MailTag MT ON M.IdMail = MT.IdMail
GROUP BY M.IdEmail,
         M.Subject,
         M.[Other...]
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN MT.idTag = 9 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN MT.idTag = 11 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

For the black list, then then same applies, but you *want* `0` in this case:

```sql
SELECT M.IdEmail,
       M.Subject,
       M.[Other...]
FROM dbo.Mail
     JOIN dbo.MailTag MT ON M.IdMail = MT.IdMail
GROUP BY M.IdEmail,
         M.Subject,
         M.[Other...]
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN MT.idTag = 9 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN MT.idTag = 11 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN MT.idTag IN (10,12) THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

---

Based on the new Goal Posts this might work, however, it doesn't return Email 6, because no such ID exists in your sample data:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO

DECLARE @Whitelist AS table (ID int UNIQUE);
INSERT INTO @Whitelist (ID)
VALUES(9),(11);

DECLARE @Blacklist AS table (ID int UNIQUE);
INSERT INTO @Blacklist (ID)
VALUES(10),(12);

WITH Mail AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'...','...'),
                (2,'...','...'),
                (3,'...','...'),
                (4,'...','...'),
                (5,'...','...'))V(IdEmail,Subject,Other)),
MailTag AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,9,1),
                (2,9,2),
                (3,9,3),
                (4,10,2),
                (5,10,3),
                (6,11,3),
                (7,12,3),
                (8,9,5),
                (9,10,5),
                (10,11,5),
                (11,12,5),
                (12,9,6),
                (13,11,6),
                (14,13,6))V(Id,IdTag,IdMail))
SELECT M.IdEmail,
       M.Subject,
       M.Other
FROM Mail M
     JOIN MailTag MT ON M.IdEMail = MT.IdMail --Why is thuis called IdEmail in one table, and IdMail in the other table?
     LEFT JOIN @Whitelist WL ON MT.IdTag = WL.ID
     LEFT JOIN @Blacklist BL ON MT.IdTag = BL.ID
GROUP BY M.IdEmail,
         M.Subject,
         M.Other
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT WL.ID) = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM @Whitelist)
   AND COUNT(BL.ID) = 0;
```

Comment: I can't write for example `CASE WHEN MT.idTag IN (9,11) THEN 1 END` because for me 9 and 11 come to the query (stored procedure) as a list/table of integers. I do not know in advance how many tags (and which ones) will be in the balck/whitelist. It's always two input tables of integers.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the above, @TheMixy ; there is no mention of procedures in your question, so I don't see why/how they are relevant. You said the data comes from a table, not a procedure.

Comment: Please see my question. I wrote that black/whitelist can have 0 or more IdTags each. It's up to the user of the app to select the tags he is searching by. So I need this part of your solution `CASE WHEN MT.idTag IN (9,11) THEN 1 END ` to be dynamic in turns of IdTags...

Comment: Are you saying you want to parametrise the query, @TheMixy ? That should have been in the question to start with...

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I thought it was implied by `White/blacklist can contain 0 or more IdTags.`

Comment: That doesn't imply parametrisatiopn, @TheMixy , just that you need a way to see how to deal with multiple values (which the above does).

Comment: I've made a guess, but it returns no results, as there is no Email 6 in your table `Mail`.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but it is very slow. I takes app. 20 seconds for a query that returns 15 records (I tested with adding just one idTag to the whitelist and one to the blacklist). Any recommendations how I could speed things up? *DB is 2019 Express version running on a new Windows 2022 server (Intel Xeon Gold processor and 12 GB available RAM).

Comment: `--Why is thuis called IdEmail in one table, and IdMail in the other table?` sorry. Just a typo in my question. It's always IdEmail in my DB.

Comment: Good indexing, presumably, @TheMixy . If it's slow then sounds like you don't have much/any indexing in your tables. That is a different question hough.

Comment: OK. I will try adding some indexes